# Use WMTS as a mask to clip a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, masking

I have loaded a WMTS layer. But when I carry out some raster geo-algorithms nothing shows up in the drop down table (i.e. I can't use the raster layer as an input object).

How do I make it possible to use it as a mask to clip polygon?

Comment: If you want to clip polygon to the extent of WMTS layer means, save your WMTS layer as raster and use 'Clip vectors by extent tool' in Processing Toolbox.